# Can’t display data from firebase realtime database, Error List<Object?> is not a subtype of Map<dynamic,dynamic>

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I’m trying to display data from my realtime database using firebase
My JSON structure
[image: My JSON structure]

(Yes I know sequential keys are bad practice and I am aware of the problems it can cause, but that's not my issue here)

If I put the path all the way to H# I can get the hName to display.

```
final testPull = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("Hotels").child("H1");
```

When I put the path just one tier higher at Hotels,

```
final testPull = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("Hotels");
```

it can’t pull the data and returns the error "type 'List<Object?>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<dynamic,dynamic>'". I obviously did change the code to account for it being a tier higher. So I know its not cause its still expecting the full path.

My goal is to be able to display all the hotel names.

I’ve done another project long ago with a similar json structure and I was able to get the same result but now it's not working for this new project.

I believe this is the website I had followed when working on the old project. I even went and did the same as they did and same issue as now.

https://petercoding.com/firebase/2020/02/16/using-firebase-queries-in-flutter/

Code following my old project.

```
final testPull = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("Hotels");
List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>> lists = [];
     FutureBuilder(
        future: testPull.once(),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DataSnapshot> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            lists.clear();
            Map<dynamic, dynamic> values = snapshot.data.value;
            values.forEach((key, values) {
              lists.add(values);
            });
            return new Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0.0, right: 0.0, bottom: 0.0),
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 153,
                child: ListView (children: new List.generate( lists.length, (int index){
                  return Card(
                    child: InkWell(
                      splashColor: Colors.purple.withAlpha(30),
                      child: Container(
                        height: 40,
                        width: double.infinity,
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                          child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Text(lists[index]["hName"]),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                }))
            );
          }
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }),
    Card(
      //height: 100,
      child: InkWell(
        splashColor: Colors.purple.withAlpha(30),
        child: Container(
          height: 40,
          width: double.infinity,
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
            child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              child: Text('Go back'),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

Thank you to Tarik Huber for the correct fix

Necessary changes:

```
List<Map<dynamic,dynamic>> values = snapshot.data.value;
```

to

```
List<dynamic> values = snapshot.data.value;
```

as well as

```
values.forEach((key, values) {
    lists.add(values);
});
```

to

```
values.forEach((key) {
    lists.add(key);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for that is that `Hotels` is already a list and not an json object that you can vonvert to a `Map`. For your code to work just change the type to a `List`:

```
List<dynamic> values = snapshot.data.value;
```

The `forEach` should also work after that.

Comment: when I change it from Map to List, the `forEach` returns type 'List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>' and I can't even run it.

If I change the `forEach` to `values.forEach((key) {
                    lists.add(key);
                  });`
I can run it but the error is "type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<Object?, Object?>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>'"

Comment: Can you pls show the new code in the answer.

Comment: i put the code in the answer, idk if you've checked the edit history

Comment: Can you pls put your code in your question.

Comment: What is the new error message you get with the latest code?

Comment: Welp looks like part of my issue was a picnic problem, as even though I showed the correct path on here, I did not have the full path in my actual code. Your answer was also necessary to get it working, but I did have to modify the forEach to what it is in the new code section.